# Find all employee who have worked on at least two projects

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Table: ProjectRessources

```
IDPRoject  IDEmployee  NumHours   PricePerHr
1          1876       500        65
1          4354       2000       31
2          2231       250        55
3          2231       500        65
3          1212       3000       35
3          1876       2000       35
```

I only come up with the following Research syntax but can't figure how to filter to only indicate 2231 and 1876:

```
SELECT IDEmployee, COUNT (*) AS ‘Number of Projects’
FROM Projectressources
GROUP BY IDEmployee;
```

Answer (score 3):

You're headed in the right direction. Your missing piece is the `having` clause that allows you filter an aggregate expression, such as `count(*)`:

```
SELECT   IDEmployee, COUNT (*) AS ‘Number of Projects’ 
FROM     Projectressources
GROUP BY IDEmployee
HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1 -- Here!
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! Worked great!